# MySQL advanced select

Tags: mysql, select

I user a simple var/val table to store my website's users info in it. The format of a user would be like this:

```
uid = 1
fname = محمد مهدی
lname = عرب
dep = 5
bday = 15
bmonth = 11
byear = 1368
cphone = 09399309399
phone = 03412815580
email = m.arab@noavaranit.com
col = B0DAFF
credit = 0
username = m.arab
password = iamnoone
lastlogin = 1406173285
admin = 1
per = 1,1
active = 1
id = 1
```

Notice that all of the users are defined with a sid which is available in every mysql row. So each of the rows above in spite of having a var and val in em they also have a sid col which is a number which defers for each user.

I need to select a user which has 2 of these row value. Example:

I need to find a user which its 'dep' is x and also its 'admin' equals to 1;

---

To clarify:

Each of the rows that u see in the above explaining a users atts are actually a row in my sql "EACH OF THESE ARE A ROW";

To clarify even more I will draw you a row

```
id     sid      var       val        date
185    12       email     xxx@xxx.xx `mysql timestamp`
283    92       name      Edward     `mysql timestamp`
```

Comment: *HELP NEEDED ASAP* <-- that is really needy

Comment: Ah! now it makes more sense... give me a minute to edit my answer!

Comment: thanks a lot, i really am desperate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `where` sounds like the solution:

```
select *
from yourTable
where dep=x -- Substitute the x with the value you need
  and admin = 1
```

Your data sample tells me that `x` must be an integer... but of course, if it's a string, enclose the value in quotes: `'x'`.

---

Your updated question makes clear what the issue is... And I think I have a solution (maybe it's not pretty, but it will work)

So, it would be something like this:

```
select t.*
from yourTable as t
     inner join (
         select sid from yourTable where var='admin' and val=1
     ) as t_admin on t.sid = t_admin.sid
     inner join (
         select sid from yourTable where var='dep' and val=x -- Replace the x with the appropriate value
     ) as t_dep on t.sid = t_dep.sid
```

Another solution would be to create a "pivot table" by hand:

```
select *
from 
    (
        select sid,
            max(case var when 'dep' then val end) as dep,
            max(case var when 'admin' then val end) as admin
        from yourTable
        where var in ('dep', 'admin')
        group by sid
    ) as a
where dep = x -- Same comment as above
  and admin = 1
```

I am assuming that no single user can have more than one entry for each var (that is, the tuple `sid, var` is unique)

Sometimes, this kind of "pivot tables" can be very slow, so it may be worth to create a temporary table, add the appropriate indexes, and then filter the data you need:

```
drop table if exists temp_aTable;
create temporary table temp_aTable
    select sid,
        max(case var when 'dep' then val end) as dep,
        max(case var when 'admin' then val end) as admin
    from yourTable
    where var in ('dep', 'admin')
    group by sid;
alter table temp_aTable
    add primary key (sid),
    add index d(dep),
    add index a(admin);
select *
from temp_aTable
where dep=x
  and admin=1;
```

Remember: temp tables are only visible to the connection that created them, and are deleted when the connection is closed.

Comment: Dude. i'm not that stupid. i know how to select a basic query.

`dep` col and `admin` col does not exist.
my columns are id-sid-var-val-date

the 'admin' and 'dep' attrs are for the var column and the value of them are in val column

get it now?

Comment: How do you know what `var` value belongs to each user? does your table structure is something like `uid, variable, value`?

Comment: I prefer the "pivot" approach

Comment: i will use the pivot approach! and I am really thankful of you for teaching me about "pivot", i know such thing existed by i had no idea how to work with it. thanks, saved my day ;)

Comment: @ametiw Happy to help ;) One final comment: your issue was indeed non-trivial, but it took a while to understand what was really going on. I am (and I'm sure every single SO regular user) always happy to help, but in order to give you the help that you need, please be sure to add as much detail to your question as possible (and wise); your data sample made things clear to me. Specifically when dealing with databases, provide a little data sample. That may be the difference between a bad  answer (or no answer at all) and a useful one.

Comment: Sure sir. i will try that, i'm basically a virgin in this kind of communities. @barranka